# Can I use two or more log levels INFO, ERROR but NOT ALL

Tags: java, logging

How to use 2 or more logging levels in an application but not ALL

Comment: we need more information Ravi

Comment: @Ravi Wadje Which logging library do you use?

Answer (score 1):

Logs are ordered. So, it's not necessary use 2 different levels.

Let's suppose you're using `log4j` API and for the standard levels we have `ALL` < `TRACE` < `DEBUG` < `INFO` < `WARN` < `ERROR` < `FATAL` < `OFF`.

This means when you setup the log level to `WARN`, everything who is being log as `WARN`, `ERROR`, `FATAL` and `OFF` will be logged.

```
|       | FATAL | ERROR | WARN | INFO | DEBUG | TRACE | ALL |
| OFF   |       |       |      |      |       |       |     |
| FATAL |   X   |       |      |      |       |       |     |
| ERROR |   X   |   X   |      |      |       |       |     |
| WARN  |   X   |   X   |  X   |      |       |       |     |
| INFO  |   X   |   X   |  X   |  X   |       |       |     |
| DEBUG |   X   |   X   |  X   |  X   |   X   |       |     |
| TRACE |   X   |   X   |  X   |  X   |   X   |   X   |     |
| ALL   |   X   |   X   |  X   |  X   |   X   |   X   |  X  |

X - is visible
```

The above table represents how log works in each level. For example, for `OFF` level nothing will be visible and for `ALL` level everything will be visible.